# Fix sound issue for Teamviewer 9 on Ubuntu 13.10 (valid also for Teamviewer 11 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: wine, pulseaudio, teamviewer

*TeamViewer* gets shipped with Wine 1.6. *Pulseaudio* is working in installed wine 1.6.1 from PPA. Copying over the `winepulse.drv.so` and `fakedlls/winepulse.drv` does not work. You can approve this with `teamviewer --winecfg`.

I've tried running *TeamViewer* with local installed wine by uncomment the line

```
### USE_LOCAL_WINE="yes"
```

in `/opt/teamviewer9/tv_bin/script/tvw_config`. But that brings other errors.

May be we can update upgrade *TeamViewers* wine to 1.6.1 instead using local installed wine.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment... To add to iRaS excellent answer, if you installed teamviewer first, then wine, a bad config/teamviewer9 may have been left over and not properly updated with "teamviewer --update-profile". If that is the case, when "teamview --wincfg" is run, you will not see any options to select when you are in the audio tab. I had to "rm -rf .config/teamviewer9", from my home directory, to get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally *TeamViewer* is running with sound (the suggested fix also works for *Teamviewer 11* on *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS* by simply considering the different path `/opt/teamviewer11/`).

This is what you need to do:

1. Add wine repository and install wine1.6:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install wine1.6
   ```
2. Download and install *TeamViewer*:

   ```
   wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb
   sudo gdebi teamviewer_linux.deb
   ```
3. Copy over wine binaries:

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/bin/wine /usr/bin/wineserver /usr/bin/wine-preloader /opt/teamviewer9/tv_bin/wine/bin/
   sudo cp /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwine.so.1.0 /opt/teamviewer9/tv_bin/wine/lib/
   sudo cp -R /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/* /opt/teamviewer9/tv_bin/wine/lib/wine/
   ```
4. Reconfigure your teamviewer profile and start winecfg to see if audio is working.

   ```
   teamviewer --update-profile
   teamviewer --winecfg
   ```

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment... To add to iRaS excellent answer, if you installed teamviewer first, then wine, a bad config/teamviewer9 may have been left over and not properly updated with "teamviewer --update-profile". If that is the case, when "teamview --wincfg" is run, you will not see any options to select when you are in the audio tab. I had to "rm -rf .config/teamviewer9", from my home directory, to get it to work.