# Audio sharing in Teamviewer

Tags: sound, teamviewer

I use Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP Desktop. I have Teamviewer installed in it, the latest version for Linux. I also have the latest version of Teamviewer installed on my HP Laptop running on Windows 8. I have enabled sharing of audio in teamviewer from my laptop, however, I am not getting that option in that in Ubuntu. As a result, I cannot hear the sound that is played on my desktop when I connect to it from my laptop. Is there any option to enable it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: We could not test this but there is a post here about audio access through Wine: http://askubuntu.com/questions/419605/teamviewer-9-ubuntu-13-10-sound